# basic php mysqli::query() does not work

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
    $query = "SELECT webpage_id FROM s_w WHERE s_w_id=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $s_w_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($webpage_id);

while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $webpage_id;  //it echos ot $webpage_id correctly which means my prepared statement works

        $query2 = "INSERT INTO webpage_point (webpage_id, point_ip) VALUES ($webpage_id, '$ip')";
        $connect->query($query2); // however this code does not work. It does not insert anything into webpage_point. Whats wrong with this basic line?
}
```

Note that: i am getting `$ip`(varchar(50)) correctly. I am sure about that too. Just two basic line and it drives me mad.

**VERY IMPORTANT EDIT:** I changed my prepared statement with a normal query and it worked.

```
    $query = "SELECT webpage_id FROM s_w WHERE s_w_id=$s_w_id LIMIT 1";
    $result = $connect->query($query);


while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $webpage_id = $row['webpage_id'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO webpage_point (webpage_id, point_ip) VALUES ($webpage_id, '$ip')";
        $connect->query($query);
}
```

So there is something wrong about `mysqli prepared statements`.

Comment: A quick way to check the query would be to echo $query2, and try running that in your SQL application

Comment: Please also specify the question outside of the code snippet, so the question is clearer :)

Comment: @Hiphop03199 damn it worked like a charm. Whatis wrong with this code? i am getting slightly mad.

Comment: @WebberDepor check my answer. You have a syntex error

Comment: @user3284463 nope. $webpage_id is an integer.

Comment: What connection library are you using? PDO, mysqli? I was going to suggest using echo($connect->get_last_error()); function or similar, depending on the library you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You are only fetching and inserting 1 row, so you don't really need 2 sql statements and a loop.

What you could do, is something like:

```
INSERT INTO webpage_point (webpage_id, point_ip)
SELECT webpage_id, '$ip' FROM s_w WHERE s_w_id=? LIMIT 1"
```

Note that you should bind the second variable - `$ip` - as well, this is just to show the complete sql in an easy way.

Comment: i already know it can be done in that way but whats wrong with my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error near `($webpage`. It should look like this:

```
$query2 = "INSERT INTO webpage_point (webpage_id, point_ip) VALUES ('$webpage_id', '$ip')"
```

Comment: I assumed $webpage_id is an integer, in which case the quotations aren't necessary. This might be a wrong assumption though.